# UILabel. Как сохранять размер лэйбла на разных экранах устройств?

Tags: ios, ios7, text

На iphone 6 лэйбл выглядит нормально. На iphone 4 часть текста не видна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`, тогда размер шрифта будет уменьшаться, чтобы текст влазил в label.

**Апдейт**

чтобы поменять программно (например сделать ширину равной ширине экрана):

```
CGRect tmp = self.label.frame;
tmp.size.width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
self.label.frame = tmp;
```

Comment: А если текст вылазит за экран?

Comment: тогда, либо использовать autolayout, либо менять `frame` програмно, в зависимости от ширины экрана

Comment: Как поменять программно?

Comment: добавил в ответ.